# Using Smart Phone displays in Raspberry Pi or other computers

Tags: display

Many smart phones aren't used after 2-3 years but the displays are good and i was wondering why no one is using those display within electrical components? Wouldn't it be great to have a module which makes it possible to use smart phone displays as general purpose displays for any computer? Is there something like thyt?

Answer (score 3):

Such LCD screens are often very difficult to use:

- the connections are via a very small and flimsy flatcable
- the intelligence is not in the display but in the main processor
- the interface is not documented
- there are lots of different versions
- on the electrical side, the interface often requires weird voltages and complex waveforms

The same arguments apply to the use of e-ink screens found in e-readers.

Note that the LCDs used in the older not-too-intelligent phones like the Nokia 5510 are sold and used a lot. These LCDS are black-and-white and low resolution (48x84), but they are cheap, easy to interface, well-documented, and there are only a few versions.

Comment: Agreed. The worst part about trying to use any screen like that is even just working out what it is, let alone finding a datasheet for it.  Many don't have any real identifying marks to even begin a hunt for specs.

Comment: Infact I recently smashed my android tablet recently just to try this. Couldn't make a head or tail of the connections, partly because they were very small, and partly because they were firmly attached to the screen. Plus they were too many.

Answer (score 0):

Some older monochrome phone displays are available as ready-made modules for Arduino and Raspberry Pi use. The Nokia 5110 is one example. I've used the Nokia 1202 display, which is 96x68 pixels, monochrome:

http://dangerousprototypes.com/2012/01/18/cheap-i2c-1-3-96x68-monochrome-lcds/

But the real problems are the tiny connectors and the lack of documentation. There are a couple of documented modules available with 0.1-inch headers (break-out boards). One is a 2.2-inch LCD with an ILI9341 controller chip, giving 320x240 pixels.

Really new smartphone displays will be higher resolution, but may have parallel interfaces that are even more difficult to connect to a microcontroller. They use these (undocumented) parallel interfaces for higher update speeds, which are required if the phone can display video.

Answer (score 0):

The MIPI DSI standard is used by quite a bunch of smartphone displays and there is a shield to use it on Raspberry Pi or anything else with HDMI out:

[MIPI DSI Display Shield/HDMI Adapter](https://hackaday.io/project/364) by twl

There is a [video demo](https://youtu.be/vCWGMM00ZEk) of a RPi driving an iPhone 4/4s screen with this shield. The board also fits on Arduino GPIO pins and it is intended that one can eventually use drawing commands on Arduino to paint into the framebuffer. For now, it's HDMI input only though.

The project is open source, PCB design and source code is available [via Github](https://github.com/twlostow/dsi-shield) (though as of 2015-01, it's the rev 2.0 software but the rev 1.0 board). So you can build it yourself if you really want (not too easy though) but as of 2015-01, the boards are not sold anywhere but it is intended for the future.